# Having trouble with local notifications with a tableview

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview, filter, uilocalnotification

I'm successful in trying to set multiple reminders for a particular event at different times. However, I'm having trouble populating my TableView with reminders or UILocalNotifications with only the notifications that pertain to a particular event when I select an event from a tableview.

I realize that I have to filter local notifications. I have scheduled my local notifications with userInfo and of course alertBody, fireDate, and etc. How can I accomplish this? Most of the examples only show the entire list instead of filter certain ones.

My code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //I want to be able to populate searchResults array on load so I can display the contents in my tableView
    NSArray *temp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

    for (int i=0; i<temp.count; i++) {
        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [temp objectAtIndex:i];
        self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:localNotif.alertBody, nil];
        NSLog(@"My objects: %@", self.searchResults);
    }
}
```

I get this log:

```
2014-03-13 10:55:42.489 My App Name[392:60b] My objects: ( "Event name" )
2014-03-13 10:55:42.492 My App Name[392:60b] My objects: ( "Event name", )
2014-03-13 10:55:42.494 My App Name[392:60b] My objects: ( "Event name", )
```

So I have three notifications set at different times. The first two have the same event name and the third is different - so the local temp array has three elements. Well first I want to be able to add all three events or notifications in the searchResults array so it will print just one time, so it will look like :

```
2014-03-13 10:55:42.489 My App Name[392:60b] My objects: ( "Event name", "Event name", "Event name" )
```

Comment: What have you tried? What did it do wrong? Show code (for configuration and filtering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your current code so that `searchResults` holds dictionaries, so you can store both the event name and other information (fire date, whatever) when you need it:

```
NSMutableArray *searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i=0; i<temp.count; i++) {
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [temp objectAtIndex:i];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict setObject:localNotif.alertBody forKey:@"body"];

    [searchResults addObject:dict;
}

NSLog(@"My objects: %@", searchResults);
self.searchResults = searchResults;
```

Comment: Thanks a million, this worked perfectly. Now I'm trying to get it to work in the tableView properly.

Comment: No problem. Please remember to up-vote answers that helped and tick answers that solve the question ;-)